# JSONKit for iphone app?

Tags: ios, json, app-store, jsonkit

Will apple choose to not allow an app to go to the app store if we use JSONKit to parse JSON's from our php document? I would like to use JSONSerializable but that is for ios5 and I am not going to alienate ios4 members on 3gs by doing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use JSONKit in an iPhone app. Apple will not reject it based on that.

It's using private APIs they get upset about. :)

Comment: Sure. If you consider this answered, please click the checkmark. It lets other SO users know the question is answered to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can import your own class or library to parse JSON that you want. So long as you aren't using anything within Apple API's that are undocumented, you will be more than fine. Those are all well established parsers. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, assumably they are unable to tell what source files you use in your application. JSONKit  is licensed under the [BSD License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses) which allows redistribution;

*Redistribution and use in source and binary forms are permitted
provided that the above copyright notice*...